# How to make Vite.js transpile the JS code in the HTML attributes like `onclick`

Tags: vite

Vite transpiles (using `esbuild`, I suppose) the code that is in JavaScript files and in the `<script>` tags.

**How to make it transpile the code inside HTML attributes, such as `onclick`?** I tried it with Vite v4, and it kept code intact despite the fact that my target browsers do not support the syntax I used. In contrast, if I use the same syntax in a separate JS file, it gets transpiled.

P.S.
In fact, my ultimate goal is to have it transpile the JS code in the Alpine.js directives, such as `x-show` etc. But to simplify the question, I've asked about the well-known attribute with JS content.

Comment: have you solved this? do you still need a solution?

Comment: Didn't solve yet. I had to manually downgrade my JavaScript in HTML attributes. And yes, a solution would be good to have.

Comment: nice, i'm on it, will try to write a simple Vite plugin that downgrades JS inside HTML attributes with esbuild

Answer (score 0):

Actually Vite compiles `<template>` into a render function and fully transpiles any JS code into the target JS version (an esbuild option) which you set with:
https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-target

```js
build:{
    target: 'es6'
}
```

In this particular case this:

```html
<script setup>
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'
import TheWelcome from './components/TheWelcome.vue'

function getMessage() {
    return (async () => {
        return 'Message';
    })();
}
function showMessage(m) {
    alert(m);
}

</script>

<template>
    <header>
        <img @click="async () => { const m = await getMessage(); showMessage(m) ?? showMessage('test'); }" alt="Vue logo" class="logo"
            src="./assets/logo.svg" width="125" height="125" />

        <div class="wrapper">
            <HelloWorld msg="You did it!" />
        </div>
    </header>

    <main>
        <TheWelcome />
    </main>
</template>
```

transformed to this:

```js
ec = {
    __name: "App",
    setup(e) {
        function t() {
            return (()=>Qt(this, null, function*() {
                return "Message"
            }))()
        }
        function n(s) {
            alert(s)
        }
        return (s,r)=>(xe(),
        Me(ce, null, [F("header", null, [F("img", {
            onClick: r[0] || (r[0] = ()=>Qt(this, null, function*() {
                var i;
                const o = yield t();
                (i = n(o)) != null || n("test")
            })),
            alt: "Vue logo",
            class: "logo",
            src: ki,
            width: "125",
            height: "125"
        }), F("div", Gl, [K(Gi, {
            msg: "You did it!"
        })])]), F("main", null, [K(Ql)])], 64))
    }
}
```

The Vite docs say that not everything could be transpiled, so when I set the target to 'es5' the build hangs without any error message which is not a good behavior, will create an issue in Vite's repository...

Your problem seems related to Alpine.js, but to solve it you should provide a full project source code where your problem is recreated.

Comment: This can be a workaround, however not applicable in every case. For example, it would be unacceptable for a statically generated website - client-side rendering goes against the architecture.

Comment: Regarding Alpine.js, the question actually is not Alpine-specific, that is why I mentioned it only in P.S. I faced the issue when I used the [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) in `onclick` and expected that Vite would transpile it.

Comment: @AKd `??` transpiled just fine, updated the answer. you should provide you component's code, vite.config.js, package.json. otherwise your case isn't reproducible

Comment: I'll try to make a reproducible repo. However I'd like to clarify that I speak about the `??` operator in the normal HTML, not in your `template` workaround.

Comment: @AKd it got clearer. anyway the code would appreciated. for example your HTML and how do you use it in your project. I'll try to check DOM template for Vue start App component. Usually it's very hard to answer a question without some minimum reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example